# Access Control List in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes

It is possible for users set up in a Group to have access to documents created by themselves only in a database. I want users to be able to create documents and only see their own documents in the view.

Comment: Thanks to you both for coming back on this, I will try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a group or any number of users to a Readers field.  The Readers field type is a special type available when you add a field to your form.  The value of the field determines who can see the document in the view.

[More info here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABOUT_RESTRICTING_ACCESS_TO_SPECIFIC_DOCUMENTS_USING_A_READERS_FIELD.html?resultof=%22reader%22%20%22fields%22%20%22field%22%20)

For example, the Readers field could have a Compute when composed formula of:

```
@Name([CN];@UserName)
```

to allow only the creator to read, or to allow only certain groups read access:

```
"MyGroupName":"My2ndGroupName"
```

Comment: Using common names in readers fields is a bad practice in my experience. Always use fully qualified names.

Answer (score 0):

Ditto Ken, plus you might find the function @UserNamesList helpful in figuring out which groups the user is a member of, so that you can assign the field to an appropriate value for that user. When using Reader fields it's sometimes a good idea to add an Authors field whose computed value lists a group that's supposed to have access to all documents.